# Google mock with templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, googlemock

I am currently trying to get templates and inheritance to behave nicely with GMock. I have a feeling what I am trying to do are two opposing ideologies and I should just use an interface, but I wanted to avoid using an interface due to possible virtual call overheads (perhaps I am optimizing prematurely)

Anyway, here's an example of what I am trying to do

```
class ConcreteObj {
public:
    // Called a lot and so don't want to hit possible virtual overhead
    void performant_function();
};

class MockObj {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, performant_function, (), ());
};

class ITest {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test_function(T& );
};

class ConcreteTest : public ITest {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test_function(T& ) {};

    template<>
    void test_function<ConcreteObj>(ConcreteObj& obj) {
        // Do something with concrete object
        obj.performant_function();
    }

    template<>
    void test_function<MockObj>(MockObj& obj) {
        // Do something with mock object
    }
}
```

What I would then like to do, is something like the following

```
ConcreteTest concrete_test;
ITest* test = &concrete_test;

// In production
ConcreteObj concrete_obj;
test.test_function(concrete_obj);

// In test
MockObj mock_obj;
test.test_function(mock_obj);
```

Which would then call `ConcreteTest` via the `ITest` interface, but the above would clearly not work without some sort of cast to the `ConcreteTest` as you can't have a virtual templated function.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas on how I could do the following, although I will probably resign myself to using a pure virtual interface and deal with the possible vtable overhead that would come if there was a `IObj` interface that `ConcreteObj` and `MockObj` inherited from.

Comment: The best way to truly have your cake and eat it too here involves making code that depends on `ConcreteObj` be templated on that type.

Comment: Also: "(perhaps I am optimizing prematurely)" If you even remotely wondering about this, then the answer is almost certainly yes.

Comment: What is the purpose of `ConcreteTest concrete_test; ITest* test = &concrete_test;`? Which class do you want to test?

Comment: I would like to test ConcreteTest whilst being able to inject the MockObj without an interface on MockObj and ConcreteObj

Comment: I don't see the point of `class ITest`. Removing it, and you can already do `concrete_test.test_function(concrete_obj);`/`concrete_test.test_function(concrete_obj);`.

Comment: Maybe you want to move the template from method to class.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Apologies, that's a limitation in the above example. Say there were a few classes inheriting from that interface, or that it's being mocked in a class that instantiates an object and uses it via ITest

Comment: @Frank - I think you could be right... On both accounts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid runtime polymorphism, you can use template, as follow:

```
class ConcreteObj {
public:
    // Called a lot and so don't want to hit possible virtual overhead
    void performant_function();
};

class MockObj {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, performant_function, (), ());
};

class ITest {
public:
    virtual ~ITest() = default;
    virtual void test_function() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
// requires (T t){ t.performant_function(); } // C++20
class ConcreteTest : public ITest {
    T t;
public:
    explicit ConcreteTest(T& t) : t(t) {}
    void test_function()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != big_number; ++i) {
           t.performant_function();
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

and then

```
// In production
ConcreteObj concrete_obj;
ConcreteTest<ConcreteObj> concrete_test{concrete_obj};
ITest* test = &concrete_test;

test->test_function();
```

```
// In test
MockObj mock_obj;
// EXPECT_CALL(..)
ConcreteTest<MockObj > concrete_test{mock_obj};
ITest* test = &concrete_test;

test->test_function();
```

Comment: Great! A nifty way of doing it! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the requirements you are specifying for `ConcreteObj`, you are asking for two things:

- Absolute minimal per-call overhead of the `performant_function()` method.
- Be able to swap-in different implementations depending on the context (i.e. when running tests vs production).

There is only one guaranteed way to get both at the same time: **templates**.

Your posted code doesn't provide a lot of context, so odds are that it's not going to be that simple, but it would look at lot like this:

```
class ConcreteTest : public ITest {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void test_function(T& obj) {
       // Do something with obj
       obj.performant_function();
    };
};

// ...
ConcreteTest concrete_test;
ITest* test = &concrete_test;

// In production
ConcreteObj concrete_obj;
test->test_function(concrete_obj);

// In test
MockObj mock_obj;
test->test_function(mock_obj);
```

However, you ask:

> (perhaps I am optimizing prematurely)

And the answer is pretty much yes. Compilers are really good at optimizing stuff. In your scenario, you could compile with `-flto` and use:

```
class IObj {
  public: 
    virtual void performant_function() = 0;
};

class ConcreteObj final : public IObj {
  public: 
    virtual void performant_function() = 0;
};
```

and that would have a solid chance of getting rid of the overhead during an optimization pass called **devirtualization**.

Comment: I think OP issue is `ConcreteTest concrete_test; ITest* test = &concrete_test;` part.

Comment: @Jarod42 I read that part as a bit of a throwaway example. From the text, it seems pretty clear to me that OP is asking for zero-cost dependency injection in general.

Comment: @Jarod42 - That is the main issue. As it would be nice to call via the interface. I have a feeling what I'm trying to do isn't going to work unless I do some dirty casting

Comment: @Frank - If I could give two answers, I would also tick this one! You pointed me in the right direction in that I was perhaps optimizing prematurely! Thanks a bunch!